# What are the coordinates of point P? SweSAT Data sufficiency

Tags: sufficient-statistics

The points $P = (x_1, y_1)$ and $Q(3, 4)$ are on the line $y=kx+m$. What are the coordinates of point $P$ ? Given

1. $m = -2$
2. $P$ is on the line $x=2$

We need both information together to solve the problem. I don't know how to approach this question. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by this...... "What are the coordinates of point P? (1) m = -2 (2) P is on the line x=2

The anser is C)"?

Comment: Information 1 and information 2

Comment: Understand now?

Comment: What is C? in "The anser is C)"

Comment: C is a answer choice

Comment: C) Information 1 and information 2 are together sufficient to solve the problem. Understand?

Answer (score 1):

Notice, substituting given value $m=-2$ in the equation of the line is $y=kx+m$, we get $$y=kx-2$$ since the point $Q(3, 4)$ lies on the above line hence it will satisfy the above equation as follows $$4=k(3)-2\implies k=2$$
hence substituting $k=2$, the equation of line is $y=2x-2$

Now, the point $P(x_1, y_1)$ lies on the line $x=2$ hence its x-coordinate is $x_1=2$. Since $P(2, y_1)$ also lies on the line: $y=2x-2$  hence substituting $x=x_1=2$ & $y=y_1$, we get $$y_1=2(2)-2=2$$ hence, the coordinates of the point $P$ are $\color{blue}{x_1=2,\ \ y_1=2}$    i.e. $\color{red}{P(2, 2)}$